# Is it possible to run a shell script excluding the last line?

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have a file `test.sh` that contains

```sh
echo "hello world";
echo "goodbye world"
```

Is it possible to execute all but the last line without having to modify the file?

Comment: how about with saving to a temporary file so that the original one isn't modified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least for simple scripts, you can modify the script file on the fly. Your script file remains unaffected by this:

```
head -n-1 test.sh | bash
```

But keep in mind, that this only removes the last line, not the last command. If your file ends with trailing new lines or comments, then only those will be removed and the last command is still executed. You can try to stripe trailing comments and newlines first, for instance with:

```
tac test.sh | sed -E '1,/^[ \t]*[^ \t#]/d' | tac | bash
```

#### Warning 1

Both approaches from above fail if the last command in your script spans multiple lines. For instance, if the last command was one of the following, then only part of the command would be removed and bash may or may not abort with a syntax error.

```
if condition; then
  body
fi
```

```
cat << eof
  text
eof
```

```
echo arg1 \
arg2
```

#### Warning 2

If your script uses functions, then this may remove a function call, and therefore more than one command. For instance, the following script would do nothing when the last "command" was removed:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
main() {
  first command
  second command
  ...
}
main
```

---

Maybe you can work around both problems by injecting a `DEBUG` trap into your script, that puffers command execution and discards the last command. But even then I can think of some cases where this could fail.

Comment: That's not _really_ modifying _the file_ is it? Just its contents (I know, I know I am being nitpicky... )

Comment: I can nitpick too :D Neither the file nor its content (that's the file after all) are modified here. Only an in-memory copy of the file is modified.

Comment: You win :D Would it be possible to somehow detect "trailing empty lines" and use that number somehow?

Comment: `head -n-1` is equivalent to `head +1`, where the plus sign means "exclude this many lines from the other end". Similar holds for `tail`.

Comment: @Socowi : Maybe we should point out that your solution implies that the script is intended for bash. This is not obvious, since the script lacks a `#!` line. A more general solution would be to parse the first line, and if that one indicates the command processor, to pipe the script into it. Or, somewhat easier, do something like `head -n-1 >tempfile && chmod +x tempfile && tempfile; rm tempfile`. Note in particular that the OP did not clearly indicate that he wants to run `test.sh` as a bash script, since the question is tagged _bash_ **and** _shell_.

Comment: @user1934428 Good observation! Makes me wonder if there is a way to use the system's shebang parser without temporary files.

Comment: The shebang is interpreted by the Kernel, when executing a file. The more interesting case is if the OP decides **not** to use a shebang, because the behaviour depends then on the running shell. I have learned from a recent discussion on SO that bash in this case catches the error returned by the kernel and then runs the script as bash script. I think zsh is doing it similarily. Don't know about i.e. sh or ksh, but having an temporary file is the safest, **but** the tempfile should be in the same directory as the script (in case the script interprets `$0`, which also fails with your solution).